# docker-compose contains an invalid type

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-pulsar

In my `docker-compose.yml` I'm getting an error when I run `docker-compose up`

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.pulsar.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

I believe the problem lies with this line:

```
ports:
    - "${HOST_PULSAR_PORT}:8999"
```

I'm not understanding the syntax of `${PORT_NAME}` or what the error is taking issue with exactly...

Comment: Do you have the environment variable `$HOST_PULSAR_PORT` set, either in a `.env` file or in the environment when you run `docker-compose up`?

Comment: It looks there is a `shell` script that has a line `export HOST_PULSAR_PORT=8999`

No `.env` file. The comment with the line just says `# Set host pulsar port - Must be exported for docker-compose.yml to use it`. Then underneath it just has the line: 
`export HOST_PULSAR_PORT=8999` From the root this script is at `scripts/run_local_service_with_pulsar.sh`.

Comment: Any progress on this?